# Youtube-dl | List of playlist videos in a Txt with file names separated by a new line

Tags: video

```
youtube-dl -i -o "%%(playlist_index)s-%%(title)s-%%(uploader)s-%%(id)s" --get-filename --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx > log.txt
```

I want the resulting output list to be separated by new line (each video filename to be separated by a line)

Answer (score 6):

If you use single percent signs it works:

```
youtube-dl -i -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s-%(uploader)s-%(id)s" --get-filename --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=..... > log.txt
```